# Use ContourPlot data in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

Let me give an example,

```
probe1 = ContourPlot[10 == x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

This plots `10=f[x,y]=x+y`, for a set of point `(x,y)` that solved the equality. Moreover,

```
probe2 = ParametricPlot[{x y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

where `g=g[x,y]=xy` and `h=h[x,y]=x^2+y^2`, plots `h=h[g[x,y]]`. What I want is to plot only the case in which `x+y=10`. What should I do?

Comment: How about a parametric region `Region[ParametricRegion[{{x y, x^2 + y^2}, 
   x + y == 10}, {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}}], Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Adding multiple mesh lines and legends:

```
mesh = {{9, Directive[Red, Opacity[1], Thick]}, 
        {10, Directive[Green, Opacity[1], Thick]}, 
        {12, Directive[Black, Opacity[1], Thick]}};

ParametricPlot[{u t, u^2 + t^2}, {u, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, t}, u + t]}, 
  Mesh -> {mesh}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[## & @@ Reverse[Transpose[mesh]], LegendLabel -> "u + t"]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use the argument of `ContourPlot` as the [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) option value in `ParametricPlot` as follows:

```
ParametricPlot[{u t, u^2 + t^2}, {u, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, t}, u + t - 10]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Do you have a sugestion to include in the same `ParametricPlot` several cases of the condition, for example `u+v-2` and `u+v-5`, etc? What should I change in your solution?

Comment: @PatrickElPollo, try `ParametricPlot[{u t, u^2 + t^2}, {u, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, t}, u + t]}, 
 Mesh -> {{{9, Directive[Red, Opacity[1], Thick]}, {10, 
     Directive[Green, Opacity[1], Thick]}, {12, 
     Directive[Black, Opacity[1], Thick]}}}]`

Comment: thanks, again. Only one more detail, sorry... is it possible to label each `Mesh` to have a legend of them?

Comment: Patrick, please see the update.

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked beautifully.

Comment: What should I do to get rid of the lightblue region?

Comment: @PatrickElPollo, you can use `PlotStyle -> White` (but that also gets rid of the right boundary)

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 10 == x + y;

ysol[x_] = y /. Solve[eqn, y][[1]]

(* 10 - x *)

Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  {x y, x^2 + y^2},
  {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}],
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{x y, x^2 + y^2} /. y -> ysol[x]],
  {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: it works, but what I want is a way to extract the pairs from `ContourPlot` when `Solve` does not work to use them as parameters in `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: @PatrickElPollo - have you tried using a numeric solver such as `NSolve` or `FindRoot`?